# Is there any way to prevent replacement of JavaScript object properties?

Tags: javascript, immutability, final

I would like to make an object's structure immutable, preventing its properties from being subsequently replaced. The properties need to be readable, however. Is this possible?

I'm sure there are no language features (along the lines of `final` in Java and `readonly` in C#) to support this but wondered whether there might be another mechanism for achieving the same result?

I'm looking for something along these lines:

```
var o = {
    a: "a",
    f: function () {
        return "b";
    }
};

var p = o.a;        // OK
o.a = "b";          // Error
var q = o.f();      // OK
o.f = function () { // Error
    return "c"; 
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ECMAScript 5 will have `seal()` and `freeze()`, but there's no good way to do this with current JavaScript implementations.

[Source](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/).

Comment: I just mentioned it for reference. I do not actively program against ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 9):

the best thing you can do is hide your properties inside of a closure.

```
var getMap = function(){
  var hidden = "1";
  return {
    getHidden : function() { return hidden; }
  }
}

var f = getMap ();

alert(f.getHidden());
```

I took a stab at it. In the above code you will need to not just return hidden but copy it into a new object perhaps. maybe you can use jquery's extend to do this for you, so you will be returning a new object, not the reference. This may be completely wrong though =)

Comment: I need the properties to be accessible from outside the object (question updated to reflect).

Comment: @Matthew So create a public access function.  See my answer.

Comment: @ivan: This isn't 4chan, don't be rude.

Comment: This is my favourite way of making the object kind of immutable, bacause the client programer has no access to the underlying vars. However, it's no 100% safe as we can always inherit from it and override the getter (I'm missing Java final methods so much here).

Comment: This will only work for primitive types and immutable properties already .... what if hidden = { "key" : "value" } ... you can still modify the contents of it .. you can't reassign it though ... but that doesn't make it immutable ... it will however behave in the same way as final in Java, but that is not immutable, non changing ...

Answer (score 5):

Using `var` in an object constructor will create a private variable.  This is essentially a closure.  Then you can create a public function to access/modify it.  More information and examples available on [Private Members in Javascript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: But then you can replace the function to return whatever you want.

Comment: @Sean Sure it can be deleted/replaced, but it cannot be altered.  I guess the bottom line is that there is no way to replace the function with something that would give direct access to the private var.

Answer (score 4):

As mkoryak said, you can create a closure to hide properties

```
function Car(make, model, color) {
    var _make = make, _model = model, _color = color; 

    this.getMake = function() {
        return _make;
    }

}

var mycar = new Car("ford", "mustang", "black");

mycar.getMake(); //returns "ford"
mycar._make; //error
```

Comment: @Zecc because that answer didn't have a code sample originally

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so there's been already a couple of answers suggesting you return an object with several getters methods. But you can still replace those methods.

There's this, which is slightly better. You won't be able to replace the object's properties without replacing the function completely. But it's still not exactly what you want.

```
function Sealed(obj) {
    function copy(o){
        var n = {}; 
        for(p in o){
            n[p] = o[p]
        }
        return n;
    }
    var priv = copy(obj);
    return function(p) {
        return typeof p == 'undefined' ? copy(priv) : priv[p];  // or maybe copy(priv[p])
    }
}

var mycar = new Sealed({make:"ford", model:"mustang", color:"black"});

alert( mycar('make') ); // "ford"
alert( mycar().make );  // "ford"

var newcopy = mycar();
newcopy.make = 'volkwagen';
alert( newcopy.make ); // "volkwagen"  :(

alert( mycar().make );   // still "ford"  :)
alert( mycar('make') );   // still "ford" :)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now force a single object property to be frozen instead of freezing the whole object. You can achieve this with `Object.defineProperty` and the parameter `writable: false`

```
var obj = {
    "first": 1,
    "second": 2,
    "third": 3
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "first", {
    writable: false,
    value: 99
});
```

In this example, `obj.first` now has its value locked to 99.