# Appropriate way to create immutable objects in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutability

I'm building an API, where I wish to make my final **returning** `object` an **immutable object**. Make the only way to change my object is to copy to another instance.

How Can I do that?

### Expected behavior:

```
var objectImmutable = api.call(id);
objectImmutable.new_var = 10;
console.log(objectImmutable.new_var)
=>undefined
//---------
var objectNotImmutable =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(api.call(id)));
objectNotImmutable .new_var = 10;
console.log(objectImmutable.new_var)
=>10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to prevent replacement of JavaScript object properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365318/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-replacement-of-javascript-object-properties)

Comment: 6 years down the line from that answer saying it was coming, we now have [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

If you want to freeze all properties you can use [deep-freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze) which is a very small script that runs recursively through the properties.

I am writing a small lib (WIP) that makes the object immutable but with the use of the API you can do operations and get the result (without changing the object since it's immutable). You can peak at the code [here](https://github.com/sideris/unmutable) if you want to get any ideas or contribute.